# Iterate through a byte array like it's Uint16[]

Tags: c#, arrays

Say I have an array like this:

```
byte[] arr = {0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88}
```

Can I somehow iterate through it with elements treated like Uint16? I want to make my application to treat it like `{0x1122, 0x3344, 0x5566, 0x7788}`.

Tried using `as` keyword but the compiler woudn't let me:

```
byte[] bytearray = new byte[10];
UInt16[] uint16array = bytearray as UInt16[];
```

Is there any way to do it? (without creating another array or casting two bytes into one uint16 every iteration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this little helper method should help you

```
public static class helper
{
    public static UInt16[] ToUnit16(this byte[] arr)
    {
        if (arr == null)
            return null;

        var len = arr.Length;

        if ((len % 2) != 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Must divide by 2");

        var count = len / 2;

        var result = new UInt16[count];
        do
        {
            result[--count] = (UInt16)((arr[--len]) | arr[--len] << 8);
        } while (count > 0);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, C# doesn't offer a way to safely reinterpret one object as if it were some different type of object (you can do it with unsafe code, but then the whole assembly winds up "unsafe").

You can use `BitConverter.ToUInt16()`, or even wrap the `byte[]` in a `MemoryStream` and use the `BinaryReader.ReadUInt16()` method to read from the byte[] object. But judging from the wording of the question, you don't want to use any method like that.

Comment: to convert it, you must include in the solution BitConverter.IsLittleEndian

Comment: Yes, the bytes would have to be swapped before using the built-in .NET implementations on a little-endian architecture (e.g. Intel x86/x64), since OP's data is big-endian (according to his question).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with unsafe code:

```
fixed(byte* p = bytearray)
{
    ushort* ptr=(ushort*)p;
    for(int i = 0; i < bytearray.Length/2; i++)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: this will not work, it will produce 0x2211, 0x4433, etc instead of 1122, 3344

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast the entire array like that, at least not in managed code. You can convert this using `BitConverter.ToUInt16`, like this:

```
UInt16[] uint16array = Enumerable
    .Range(0, arr.Length/2)
    .Select(i => BitConverter.ToUInt16(arr, 2*i))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: This will produce little endian behavior where the question requests big endian behavior.

Comment: this would work if you implement in it the endian, BitConverter.IsLittleEndian